# GROFF PDFPIC converted w ImageMagick to .ms document causes "troff: sample.ms:18: division by zero" and leads images to show very right of the pdf doc

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, groff, troff

I converted my original image to pdf with ImageMagick. If viewed independently, the pdf image looks perfectly normal.

sample.ms :

```
.PDFPIC Figure_1.pdf
```

Once I try to compile my .ms document with the following command:

```
groff -ms sample.ms  -U -T pdf > sample.pdf
```

I get the following error from groff:

```
troff: sample.ms:1: division by zero
```

The document does compile but it looks like this: image is way to the right of the page to the point its sometimes almost completely out of the page.

[image]

Comment: Try asking on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Make sure you have installed the poppler-utils package and so have the `pdfinfo` command.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and it seems like the PDFs `convert` generates are corrupt in some way.

I ended up using `convert img.png img.tiff` and then `tiff2pdf img.tiff > img.pdf`. Including `img.pdf` then worked just fine.

I used `tiff2pdf` just because that's what I had installed, but any other program should work too if it generates valid PDF.